# .htaccess throws a 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and need to get rid of the "index.php" in the URL.
I copied the .htaccess file from codeigniter tutorial, emptied the $config['index_page'] = '';
and put the .htaccess in the root directory.
Without the .htaccess file it works fine, but ugly: www.example.com/index.php/site/home
For some reason it's not working and just throws a 500's error.

Where is the bug and how can I resolve it?

Thank you in advance

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folders by users.
    #Additionly this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have not been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^{.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
<IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php? and everything works as normal.
    # submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My site controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->home();
    }
    public function home(){
        echo "default function started.<br/>";
        $this->hello();
        $data['title'] = 'Home!';
        $data['name'] = 'Ilia';
        $data['fname'] = 'Lev';
        $data['operation'] = 'minus';
        $data['val1'] = 5;
        $data['val2'] = 7;
        echo $data['operation']."<br/>";
        $data['result'] = $this->math($data);
        $this->viewLoad("home_view", $data);
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    public function hello(){
        echo "hello function started.<br/>";
    }
    public function math($data){
        $operation = $data['operation'];
        $val1 = $data['val1'];
        $val2 = $data['val2'];
        $this->load->model("math");
        return $this->math->calculate($operation, $val1, $val2)."<br/>";
    }
    public function viewLoad($whatToView, $data){
        try{
            $this->load->view($whatToView, $data);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "There is no such view";
        }
    }
    public function about(){
        $data['title'] = "About!";
        $this->viewLoad("about_view",$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` installed, and did you `restart apache` after including the `htaccess` file? Also is your CodeIgniter installed in a sub directory called `knight-guard.org`?

Comment: Didn't restart apache, and I don't know about the mod_rewrite because I either don't have an access to the moduls installed on my server or don't know where to find it.

Comment: Just restarted apache - still the same problem

Comment: Apache has a `error.log`. Look there when you receive a server error.

Comment: Just incase my last comment wasn't clear. You should double check your `RewriteBase /knight-guard.org/`, this is normally just `RewriteBase /` unless your application is inside a sub directory. Also remember to always `restart apache` after making changes to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Looked in the errorlog - there is this row repeating itself:[Thu Dec 20 03:53:43 2012] [alert] [client 2.55.118.161] /home/morro1980/data/www/knight-guard.org/.htaccess: <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments

Comment: Yes of course. I removed the 'knight-guard.org/' and restarted apache. Thank you.

Comment: So did that fix your issue?

Comment: Just received an answer from my server support that the mod_rewrite is installed and working. But the problem persist...

Comment: OP was not happy with the help from you all in this thread, so he just started another one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964867/500-error-thrown-due-to-htaccess-bug

Answer (score 3):

If this is really part of the `.htaccess` file, it would cause your problem:

```
RewriteRule ^{.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
            ^^^ typo?
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Mm... Where is the '^^^ typo?' in the above code? Or i just didn't really understood you...

Comment: @Ilia Lev `(` instead of `{`.

Comment: @llialev around `line 10` in your .htaccess you have a curly brace `{` and that should be a parentheses `(`

Comment: @Ilia Lev You should answer Steven Farley's last question below your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP bailed out and went elsewhere:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964867/500-error-thrown-due-to-htaccess-bug

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem but my code was correct and i was using wamp server, then 
I found rewrite module is not enabled

so went to apache/conf/httpd.conf and uncommented line

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Now its working fine.